# Skype on 12.04 x64 does not start even after purging and reinstalling it

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, skype

I am wondering if there's anyone here who managed to use Skype on 12.04. It used to work (ever since I first tried Ubuntu 10.04) flawlessly, but after upgrading to 12.04, it just doesn't start.

If I start Skype from terminal, it just says `Segmentation fault (core dumped).`
I tried to remove Skype and installed it from different locations:

- Skype website (did not install at all, "package error")
- From official Ubuntu repository (doesn't start at all, segmentation fault)
- From repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner" (doesn't start at all, segmentation fault)

Interesting thing: even if I remove / purge Skype from the system, it still shows up in Unity menu (of course doesn't start).

Any help here?

Comment: I installed skype from their website and except for some rare and minor quirks it works perfectly. What does the coredump say?

Comment: some users reported this error to go after uninstalling the `Globalmenu` from the sofware center. try that and see

Answer (score 18):

Skype is working very well on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit version (using it right now).

How to:

1. Go to **Software Sources**, click on second tab **Other Software** and mark **Canonical Partners** and **Canonical Partners (Source Code)**.
2. Open your terminal and add the following command  `sudo apt-get update`.
3. After the update is completed please type  `sudo apt-get install skype`. 
   This will install skype and will work perfectly.

Good luck.

Comment: for an entirely command line method, edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` as root and uncomment the two partner lines as explained in the comments in that file. Then do steps 2 and 3 above.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/a/62457/36661

Comment: +1 Tried it and it works on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly, though you should mention that Software Sources is found through `Ubuntu Software Centre -> Edit (..in Taskbar menus..) -> Software Sources`

Answer (score 4):

Skype works fine for me on 12.04 x64, and I did not have to reinstall it after the upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by using skype *on* Ubuntu 12.04 x64.  Are you using a x64 version of Skype, or do you just want to be able to use Skype on your 64 bit machine?  Historically Skype hasn't released a native x64 version for linux, so I've always used the i386 version with the i386 libraries.

I just noticed that there is a new package in the respositories which looks like it could be a native x64 version but I haven't tried it.

The version I'm using is Skype (beta) version 2.2.0.35 (package is skype:i386 version: 2.2.0.35-0precise3)

You could try using the i386 version if you aren't already if having a native x64 app isn't that important to you.

Answer (score 3):

I can only repeat that Skype works well for me. It took quite a while to install (Installed it from their website with the Software-Center), but now it runs as my previous versions of it.

Comment: This does answer the question, but I think the OP needs to refine the question to get useful information, perhaps.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure that your Apparmor profile for Skype (if you have any) isn't the cause of the problem.

I have had very similar symptoms (skype was simply coredumping), and removing my hand-written long ago Apparmor profile for Skype (`/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.skype`) resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Install method for Skype 4.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit:

1. `apt-get remove skype`
2. `apt-get autoremove`
3. Go to official Skype Web Site, choose Get Skype for Linux it will show Ubuntu 11.10 32- and 64-bit.
4. Choose 64-bit and open it with Software Center.
5. Install it, and it should work.

I believe there are some issues with Skype's icon not showing up. So I've tried this method and it works, but because of those issues, I prefer the official version existing in Ubuntu's official repositories (Skype Beta 2.2).

Answer (score 2):

Yes I've been using Skype on 12.04 x64 which is working fine,
Download "Skype Static" from official website and if it wouldn't run just install the package "ia32-libs" through software center.

Answer (score 0):

I installed successfully without any issue ... 
steps i followed on  below link

http://www.kartook.com/2012/05/ubuntu-how-to-install-skype-on-amd-64-bit-ubuntu-12-04-precise/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that installing from Ubuntu repositories (as explained in the above solutions) install a 2.2 version of Skype.

```
#> skype --version
Skype 2.2.0.35
Copyright (c) 2004-2011, Skype Limited
```

The official Skype website offers a 4.0 version of Skype for Ubuntu 32/64bit. To install it, download the `.deb` package from the website([32bit](http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-beta-ubuntu-32) or [64bit](http://www.skype.com/go/getskype-linux-beta-ubuntu-64)), then run:

`aptitude install lib32stdc++6 libstdc++6 lib32asound2 ia32-libs libc6-i386 lib32gcc1`

and then

`dpkg -i skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.8-1_amd64.deb` (or its 32bit counterpart)

At the end you will have a 4.0 version of Skype installed.

```
#> skype --version
Skype 4.0.0.8
Copyright (c) 2004-2012, Skype
```

Answer (score 0):

https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/skype4

Easiest way to install latest Skype 4 and keep it updated, works brilliantly on my 12 core desktop and quad core laptop as well as on netbook, all running x64 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Update manager recently updated my skype version from
skype-bin:i386 2.2.0.35-0precise3
to
skype-bin:i386 4.0.0.8-0oneiric1

sadly, the new version exhibits lower quality voice playback, video bugs and occasional crashes.

So, may not work for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

To Install Skype in Ubuntu 12.04 you need to get the canonical repository

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skype
```